# blazor freezes after post request

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Edit: I took a break and tried again and now it works. I didnt even change the code ! Can someone explain me why it didnt work and now it does without any changes? I am very confused.

I have a Blazor server app and an asp.net core webapi. If i do a getasync() I can perfectly retrieve all data from my api. When I do a post however it freezes and stops doing anything. When I look at the command window that opens it says:

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.BedrijvenApiClient.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 1067.2083ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.BedrijvenApiClient.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 1074.1642ms - 200
```

So it clearly receives the post. So I don't understand why it does nothing afterwards. It doesnt even throw an exception. I have tested the api and I do get a result in postman.
The code to do the request is in the following function:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostBedrijfAsync(string b)
    {
        var y = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<string>($"/bedrijven/{b}","");
        return y;
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can actually do post requests if this method is not correct? Am I missing something? Do I have to add something extra in program.cs? am I missing a package?

controller method in the class bedrijvencontroller

```
        public async static Task<OBedrijf?> CreateBedrijf(string btw)
    {
        Bedrijven x = await Bedrijven.GetCreateByVat(btw);
        return x == null ? null : new OBedrijf(x.id, x.Naam, x.Co, x.BTW, x.Straat, x.Nummer, x.Bus, x.Zip, x.Stad, x.Taal, x.Opmerking, x.Email, x.Betalingsvoorwaarden, x.voordeeltarief);
    }
```

The function itself seems to work without issues when called and does return a new OBedrijf when called from the blazor webapp. It also returns a new OBedrijf as json when i call it from Postman.
It is mapped in program like so:

```
RouteGroupBuilder bedrijvenApi = app.MapGroup("/bedrijven");
bedrijvenApi.MapPost("/{btw}", (string btw) => BedrijvenController.CreateBedrijf(btw));
```

Comment: Could you please show us the controller method?  You might also try passing null instead of an empty string as the second parameter.

Comment: I 've added the controller method and I will move the b parameter back to the body as soon later.